# Problemas Meta Slider WordPress 4.9.1

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Boa noite.

Estou desenvolvendo um tema do zero em WordPress e tenho o plugin meta slider instalado no meu tema.

Porém quando eu coloco o shortcode no meu post ele não aparece na página. Mas se eu der um inspect eu consigo ver que ele trouxe as imagens. Mas não printa na tela.

Alguém sabe me dizer se tenho que fazer alguma configuração no functions.php?

Att,
Maurício.

Comment: Coloca o HTML completo com o CSS, sem isso fica difícil te ajudar. E confere se o caminho das imagens está correto.

Comment: Bom dia. Desculpa a demora. Assim que eu chegar em casa eu coloco o código aqui. Att, Maurício.